# Change code to throw illegalPositionException

Tags: java, exception, arguments

Hi I the code for class Crane below:

```
public class Crane {
    protected int position;
    public static final int MIN_POSITION = 0;
    public static final int MAX_POSITION = 10;

    public Crane(){
        this.position = MIN_POSITION;
    }

    public int getPosition(){
        return this.position;
    }

    public void setPosition(int newPosition){
        this.position = newPosition;
    }

    public void move(int distance){
        int endPosition = this.position + distance;
        this.setPosition(endPosition);
    }
}
```

I need to rewrite the move method to throw an illegalPositionException 'where appropriate'.

I thought of adding:

```
if ((0 > endPosition) || (10 < endPosition)
  throw new IllegalPositionException("...");
end
```

Not too sure if that would work or if I need to use a try-catch block.

Also worth noting the IllegalPositionException has to be defined and created which is done separately.

thanks

Comment: First at all you need to know what IllegalPositionException is, if checked or unchecked Exception https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/checked-vs-unchecked-exceptions-in-java/amp/  after that you will be able to know if it is necessary to have try/catch block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IllegalPositionException` can be thrown like this:
(Assumption: `distance` parameter can be negative.)

```
public void move(int distance) {
    int endPosition = this.position + distance;
    if (MIN_POSITION > endPosition || MAX_POSITION < endPosition) {
        throw new IllegalPositionException("Invalid end position: " + endPosition + " when moved by " + distance);
    }
    this.setPosition(endPosition);
}
```

When you throw an exception from a method, there is no point in catching it in that method itself. Exceptions are thrown to be caught and handled at higher levels.

If `IllegalPositionException` is a checked exception, then we have to add `throws IllegalPositionException` to the method signature like this:

```
public void move(int distance) throws IllegalPositionException
```

Comment: would I not need to change move to public void move(int distance) throws IllegalPointerException { ... }

Comment: I just edited my answer and mentioned about this. Yes, if it is a checked exception, then we have to add `throws` clause.

Comment: Perfect Thankyou very much :)